# Downloading source code for JDK 1.4.1_07

Tags: java

I have been trying to find the source code for JDK 1.4.1_07 but i cant seem to find it anywhere. The closest i have come to is the archives on the oracle/sun website.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase14-419411.html#j2sdk-1.4.1_07-oth-JPR

The above points to the archives but they are all binaries. None of them include the source code. Does anyone know where i can get the source code from?

Thanks

Comment: Interesting question. I doubt there's much of the sort out there since Java wasn't in fact open sourced, and OpenJDK conceived, until sometime in 2006-2007, well into the development of JDK6. Please answer this question yourself, should you find it before someone else!

Comment: Thanks. I found the source inside the binary file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, the JDK by default comes with a "src.zip" file which contains the source code of the Java classes of the JDK. Are you looking for something else?

Comment: No that is what i was looking for. I downloaded the binary and installed it and it did include the source.zip file in it. Thanks.